# What plug-in do I need to create a web application in Net Beans

Tags: netbeans, configuration

I just installed NetBeans on my local system.     I want to create a Web application but when I click on File->New Project-> The dialogue box that pops up does not give a Web option (I know one exists because I've seen it in text books).    Instead I see Java, Maven, NetBeans Modules as my options.    Is there a plug in that I need so that the Web option appears?

Thank you,

Elliott

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you didn't download the correct download bundle.

The [NetBeans download page](http://netbeans.org/downloads/) shows an overview of all available bundles. From your description it seems that you have the JavaSE package. But you will need the JavaEE package.

As stated on the same page you can add modules:

> You can add or remove packs later
>   using the IDE's Plugin Manager (Tools
>   | Plugins).